# Importing a type twice causes MEF to fail

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to write a small module system with MEF, so I have a base module like so:

```
public abstract class Module : IModule
{
    [Import]
    private IShell _shell;

    protected IShell Shell
    {
        get { return _shell; }
    }
}
```

And a few modules like so:

```
[Export(typeof(IModule))]
public class TodoListModule : Module
{

}
```

As you see, the base module is dependent on an IShell. I have 1 implementation of that, like so:

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : IShell
{
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<IModule> _modules;

    .... and later...

    private void InitializeModules()
    {
        foreach (var module in _modules)
        {
            // init modules.
        }
    }
}
```

So the shell is responsible for loading modules.

The problem is when I have more than 1 module implementation, I get this exception:

```
GetExportedValue cannot be called before prerequisite import '...ShellViewModel..ctor' has been set.
```

So, the cause is the fact that we have 2 implementations that are getting an `IShell` thru the base class. Why is this happening?

This is my container config:

```
        // Add all assemblies to AssemblySource (using a temporary DirectoryCatalog).
        var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"./");
        AssemblySource.Instance.AddRange(
            directoryCatalog.Parts
                .Select(part => ReflectionModelServices.GetPartType(part).Value.Assembly)
                .Where(assembly => !AssemblySource.Instance.Contains(assembly)));

        // Prioritise the executable assembly. This allows the client project to override exports, including IShell.
        // The client project can override SelectAssemblies to choose which assemblies are prioritised.
        var priorityAssemblies = SelectAssemblies().ToList();
        var priorityCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(priorityAssemblies.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)));
        var priorityProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(priorityCatalog);

        // Now get all other assemblies (excluding the priority assemblies).
        var mainCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(
            AssemblySource.Instance
                .Where(assembly => !priorityAssemblies.Contains(assembly))
                .Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)));
        var mainProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(mainCatalog);

        container = new CompositionContainer(priorityProvider, mainProvider);
        priorityProvider.SourceProvider = container;
        mainProvider.SourceProvider = container;

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();

        BindServices(batch);
        batch.AddExportedValue(mainCatalog);

        container.Compose(batch);
```

This also happens when any other class is importing `IShell`

Comment: Why do you need Compose? This funktion is nice when you are dealing with unkown objects that trys to Ref Modules. Maybe this could help you [Plugin based Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682642/Using-a-Plugin-Based-Application). There i describe how the importing of batches is working and you can download a working solution that is able to Compose
And is it Possible that IShell Inherts from IModule? If so you are maybe stuck in a Circular dependency while you try to Compose due the Ctor of ShellViewModel

Comment: @JPVenson IShell does not inherit IModule. The config code is part of some bootstrapping code I found for Caliburn.Micro. I have a working solution already, but I can't figure out what is being done differently, as the config code is from there.